# Bank wasn't able to verify your VISA while payment

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox, payment

I am new to PayPal integration I am testing the payment process but facing some issue while checking out. I tried all mention cards in PayPal website but didn't work any.

**Error Message:**

> Sorry, your bank wasn't able to verify your VISA x-**** at this time.
>   Please choose another way to pay.

Comment: Have you resolved this issue. if yes please share the solution.

Comment: Yes, you have to test with dummy card numbers which are given by PayPal or nay other payments method

Comment: Yes, i am using dummy cards those provided by paypal but still i am getting this message.

Comment: I am also facing same issue, googled this, and tried many things but didnt work any. so raised ticket on support. let see what happened..

Comment: Is any update on this issue. Iam facing the same issue. Kindly post the answer if you got it working. Thanks.

Comment: https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/Payments/Sorry-your-bank-wasn-t-able-to-verify-your-VISA-at-this-time/m-p/1779461

Hope, this link would be helpful

Answer (score 4):

Go to the PayPal Dashboard from the account from which you created the Sandbox accounts and PayPal app. There in the **Mock** section in the side navigation go to **Credit Card Generator**. Here select the country that you have chosen while making the business sandbox account and click **Generate CC**.
Now copy the details of the card generated. Now go to the site where you have integrated PayPal checkout and while making payment instead of choosing the default card click on add Debit/Credit card and add a card with the details the card that you generated. You'll be redirected to a payment page, fill a random password there and your dummy transaction will be completed if everything else in the code is fine.

Answer (score 2):

You need to go to your paypal developer account and then find the mock menu and then select credit card generator

Generate a credit card based on your county

[image]

Now try to add a new card on the Paypal page where you are getting error.
[image]

Enter the details of the mock card

Then again try to do that payment.
You may be asked to enter a password. Just click on the new-user/forgot password link.
Everything will work fine

Answer (score 0):

I faced this similar issue while integrating Paypal with my app. What I did found that Paypal integration for sandbox account does have an issue while payment if the currency used, is other than USD.

Yes, other solution may work if you want to generate a fake credit card and add it to the Paypal page.

But if you don't want to add any other credit card to the Paypal account and use it for testing purposes, what you can do is to change the country of both business and personal accounts to USA & currency to USD, also set the app to accept the payment in USD.
It will work fine.